# How can I filter a XML before importing it/link it to a map in Excel

Tags: xml, excel, vba, xpath

How can I filter a XML before importing it/link it to a map in Excel

I want to filter a XML to one record an then import the record to excel by linking it to a map.
By now I can only achieve this by doing the following:

1. Filtering the node with an XPath Expression as an IXMLDOMNode
2. Get the xml string of the node
3. Extending the string with the root node tags
4. Assign the string to the map with .ImportXml(...)

I wonder if there is an easier way to do this, especially Step 3 (extending the string) seems to be a little bit complicated.

Remark: The example xml is taken from "Excel 2007 VBA Programmers Reference".

Many thanks in advance

Andre

VBA Code:

```
Sub FilterNode()
    Dim oXmlDoc As DOMDocument60
    Dim oXmlNode As IXMLDOMNode
    Dim strXml As String
    Dim oMap As XmlMap

    'Filter xml
    Set oXmlDoc = New DOMDocument60
    oXmlDoc.async = False
    oXmlDoc.Load (ThisWorkbook.Path & "\EmployeeSales.xml")
    Set oXmlNode = oXmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//Employee[Empid=24601]")
    strXml = oXmlNode.XML

    'Extend xml String
    'is this really necessary?
    strXml = "<EmployeeSales>" & vbCrLf & strXml & vbCrLf & "</EmployeeSales>"

    'link xml with map
    Set oMap = ThisWorkbook.XmlMaps(2)
    oMap.ImportXml (strXml)
End Sub
```

Sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<EmployeeSales>
     <Employee>
          <Empid>2312</Empid>
          <FirstName>Mike</FirstName>
          <LastName>Alexander</LastName>
          <InvoiceNumber>100</InvoiceNumber>
          <InvoiceAmount>2300</InvoiceAmount>
     </Employee>

     <Employee>
          <Empid>24601</Empid>
          <FirstName>Stephen</FirstName>
          <LastName>Bullen</LastName>
          <InvoiceNumber>200</InvoiceNumber>
          <InvoiceAmount>3211</InvoiceAmount>
     </Employee>
</EmployeeSales>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code sample given is the best approach.